# How to know end of a single event of Server-Sent Event?

Tags: spring, flutter, server, server-sent-events

I have for example, the following server code:

```
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().id("id").name("eventName").data(dummyData.getName()));
delay(10);
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().id("id").name("eventBalance").data(dummyData.getBalance()));
delay(5000);
emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().id("id").name("eventHistory").data(dummyData.getHistory()));
emitter.complete();
```

When I receive it on client side (I use flutter, but I believe that does not matter), I get the events like this:

```
I/flutter (17221): id:id
I/flutter (17221): event:eventName
I/flutter (17221): data:Joe
I/flutter (17221):
I/flutter (17221): id:id
I/flutter (17221): event:eventBalance
I/flutter (17221): data:2511
I/flutter (17221):
I/flutter (17221): id:id
I/flutter (17221): event:eventHistory
I/flutter (17221): data:[{"dateTime":"2022-04-22T19:01:38.184845+01:00","value":"somevalue"}]
I/flutter (17221):
I/flutter (17221): done
```

I printed only the body here. As far as I can see, the only thing that signals an event is sent completely in the stream (all of this is in a single stream) is an emppy line. But what if the request had an empty line too?

Answer (score 0):

I found that Server-Sent Events use double newline to separate events, there is no other way to know.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format